# Who, or What Am I?

Tags: riddle

Turn me on

Or turn me off

Just push my buttons

To get from me

The information

Which could be key

I can be basic, simple

4 different types, or symbols

I may be smarter, more complex

Find answers in many more steps

Whether a feature, or whether an object

You can be sure what I tell you will be correct

Comment: What is the reason here for the downvotes? Just curious as to what I've done wrong? Too easy, maybe?

Comment: Reads very awkwardly and choppy.. It looks as though it should have a rhyme or rhythm but it doesn't really.. And if read appropriately as the commas are placed, it sounds odd.. Could be part of why, or the easiness

Comment: @n_palum Hmmm, maybe. I thought it flowed quite well (There are supposed to be 2 halves to it, 5 lines each). I'll try and work on the presentation in future then, I guess.

Comment: You should indicate there are two halves.. And there are random rhymes like me/key in the middle of it but no where else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was easy, You are:

> a calculator

Because:

> You can be turned on and off, you have 4 symbols (at least, the basic one do have 4 symbols), can find answers in more steps, every result is correct, can do simple operation but also complex one and it is used to get the 'Information which could be the key'.

Comment: I answered first and you got the vote :( lol

Comment: You are right, but that's because I explained the reasons of my choice, that is how it should be done @larkwiot

Comment: @larkwiot Yeah I didn't give you the vote because you didn't explain how you got to that answer, or why. As Techidiot mentioned, it's best to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a calculator?

Just taking a guess here...

> Because the 4 symbols are + - / X and you can turn a calculator on and off and it gives you crucial or key information and it is always right (technically it isn't always, but for the purposes here it is).

Comment: Looks like it. You can explain each line of the riddle and that should be good.

Comment: @Techidiot Thanks for making the spoiler work, I was having trouble